# Unable to receive push notification from fcm in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send  push notification from FCM .But unable to receive it in my android device.
At first you can see in the image that it's not getting initialized but later the initialization is successful. 
I am able to get the FCM registration id but unable to get the push message .

here is the screenshot:
[image: Logcat]

OnReceive Method :

```
   mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
             @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };
```

I am using this example of [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and I have also tried to test it on different devices with different versions.

if anyone can give some idea then it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: how you sending push notifictaion?

Comment: from google's fcm

Comment: i mean using your own server or fcm console?

Comment: I am sending it from FCM's console

Comment: The thing which is not initialized first time is not related to push notification.It is related to crash reporting.

Comment: did you add service in menifest file and use same reg token to send notification?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yes I did and also tried to send it by regd token

Comment: can you post it? and add onMessageReceived method?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yes it's in the screenshot you can see it there

Comment: your code of OnMessageReceived service class

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Edited

Comment: I can't see any changes??

Comment: @DivyeshPatel added the changes

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I have to add the dependencies but it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142602/discussion-between-sushrita-and-divyesh-patel).

Comment: there is no need to use Brodcast Receiver just simply use public class MyFcm extends FirebaseMessagingService